# Looping each record of a table and inserting data into a temp table joining another temp table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have two temporary table  `#CoreUtilizationForRole1` and  `#RoleID2Details`. I want to insert values into a third temp table using these two temp table.
Below are the table Structure of both the Temp table.

```
create table #CoreUtilizationForRole1(roleid int,SupervisorName varchar(50),ImmediateSupervisor varchar(50),UserECode varchar(50),UserName nvarchar(250),Designation varchar(250),TimeSpent float,ActivityName varchar(250))

create table #RoleID2Details(UserECode varchar(50),UserName nvarchar(250))
```

in `#CoreUtilizationForRole1` table I had generated a report and stored in it. `#RoleID2Details` contains data as mentioned below in the query:-

```
insert into #RoleID2Details
    select distinct Userecode,Username from #CoreUtilizationForRole1 where roleid=2
```

Now I want to loop through each records of  `#RoleID2Detail`s and insert data into a third temp table while joining from `#CoreUtilizationForRole1`.
AcTually I need data in a particular described format and due to that, this looping is required so that I insert data into third temp table as per my requirement and then using a simple select statement I will display it.

The third table Structure will be -

```
create table #ThirdtempTable(roleid int,SupervisorName varchar(50),ImmediateSupervisor varchar(50),UserECode varchar(50),UserName nvarchar(250),Designation varchar(250),TimeSpent float,ActivityName varchar(250))
```

and the logic for inserting data into `#ThirdtempTable` is like this looping each records of `#RoleID2Details` table-

```
insert into #ThirdtempTable
Select A.RoleId,A.SuperVisorName,A.Userecode,A.Username,A.Designation,A.TimeSpent,A.ActivityName 
from #CoreUtilizationForRole1 A 
inner join #RoleID2Details B 
on
A.SuperVisorName=B.UserName
where B.UserECode= --First UserECode from #RoleID2Details

insert into #ThirdtempTable
Select A.RoleId,A.SuperVisorName,A.Userecode,A.Username,A.Designation,A.TimeSpent,A.ActivityName 
from #CoreUtilizationForRole1 A 
inner join #RoleID2Details B 
on
A.UserName=B.UserName
where A.UserECode=--First UserECode from #RoleID2Details
```

this looping will go until we extract all the records from `#RoleID2Details` table and insert it as mentioned above into `#ThirdtempTable` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into #your3rdTempTable
select distinct t1.UserECode,t1.UserName from
#CoreUtilizationForRole1 t1 join #RoleID2Details t
on t1.UserECode=t2.UserECode and t1.UserName = t2.UserName
```

You can try this way:

```
insert into #ThirdtempTable
Select A.RoleId,A.SuperVisorName,A.Userecode,A.Username,A.Designation,A.TimeSpent,A.ActivityName 
from #CoreUtilizationForRole1 A 
inner join #RoleID2Details B 
on
A.SuperVisorName=B.UserName
where B.UserECode=A.UserECode

insert into #ThirdtempTable
Select A.RoleId,A.SuperVisorName,A.Userecode,A.Username,A.Designation,A.TimeSpent,A.ActivityName 
from #CoreUtilizationForRole1 A 
inner join #RoleID2Details B 
on
A.UserName=B.UserName
where A.UserECode=A.UserECode
```

Comment: Updated my question. I want to loop through each records as i want to insert data into a specific sequence.

Comment: Loop each userecode from #RoleID2Details table and insert into #ThirdtempTable and the sequence of inserting data into #ThirdtempTable is mentioned in my question.

Comment: Check the updated answer.Now it will do what you wanted it to do